# Errors when trying to run Flask's testsuite

Tags: python, testing, flask, pytest

I followed [*how to contribute to Flask*](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.rst) tutorial.

When I run `pytest tests/*.py`, the tests pass  but when I run simply `pytest` (as asked on the reference above), I get this error message:

```
pytest
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.5.2, pytest-3.0.7, py-1.4.33, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /home/begueradj/flask, inifile: setup.cfg
collected 377 items / 3 errors 

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
____________ ERROR collecting examples/flaskr/tests/test_flaskr.py _____________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/begueradj/flask/examples/flaskr/tests/test_flaskr.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
examples/flaskr/tests/test_flaskr.py:15: in <module>
    from flaskr import flaskr
E   ImportError: No module named 'flaskr'
__________ ERROR collecting examples/minitwit/tests/test_minitwit.py ___________
ImportError while importing test module '/home/begueradj/flask/examples/minitwit/tests/test_minitwit.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
examples/minitwit/tests/test_minitwit.py:14: in <module>
    from minitwit import minitwit
E   ImportError: No module named 'minitwit'
_____ ERROR collecting examples/patterns/largerapp/tests/test_largerapp.py _____
ImportError while importing test module '/home/begueradj/flask/examples/patterns/largerapp/tests/test_largerapp.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
examples/patterns/largerapp/tests/test_largerapp.py:1: in <module>
    from yourapplication import app
E   ImportError: No module named 'yourapplication'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 3 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
=========================== 3 error in 2.78 seconds ============================
```

My environment is:

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
- Python 3.5.2
- pytest version 3.0.7

Why did this occur and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Now that Flask 1.0 is out, `pytest` alone will only run the tests in the `tests` directory. After installing the examples, use `pytest tests examples` to test both.

```
pip install -e examples/tutorial
pip install -e examples/javascript
pytest tests examples
```

---

The contributing docs <del>are</del> were out of date, you need to run `pytest tests`. If you want to test the examples (which is what's failing now) you need to install them like `tox` does.

```
pip install -e examples/flaskr
pip install -e examples/minitwit
pip install -e examples/patterns/largerapp
pytest
```

---

Alternatively, run `tox -e py` to run the entire test suite, or `tox` to run the suite on all supported Python versions.